# Pointer shows junk for some reason

Tags: c

I have a problem with my pointer. I have a void function which i want to return something. A subject to be exact. So, i use a pointer. The problem is that when i ask the user to enter the subject and then my function is called, my pointer returns garbage along with the given subject. Like, "some weird character"ava, instead of Java. I suspect that my scanf in the announc function is faulty, but i really have no idea why i dont get my subject right.

```
void announc(char day1[10], char day2[10], char date1[5], char date2[5], int class1, int class2, char *subject);
int main()
{
    char day1[10], day2[10], date1[5], date2[5];
    char subject[10];
    int class1, class2;
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %d %d", day1, date1, day2, date2, &class1, &class2);
    announc(day1, day2, date1, date2, class1, class2, subject);
    printf("subject: %s\n", subject);
    return 0;
}
void announc(char day1[10], char day2[10], char date1[5], char date2[5], int class1, int class2, char *p)
{

    printf("something");
    *p = scanf("%s", p);

}
```

Comment: What is `*p = scanf("%s", p)` supposed to do? You know what [`scanf` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)?

Comment: I forgot one %s but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*p = scanf("%s", p);
```

Not sure what you were intending with this. `scanf` returns the number of arguments filled, (i.e. 1). You're then assigning that result to the first element of `p`. When printed, you see the terminal's attempt to print the character with ASCII value 1 (followed by the remainder of the string, which is unaffected).

Simply don't do that! The action you need performing, the input of a string into the thing pointed-to-by `p`, is achieved without touching the return value:

```
scanf("%s", p);
```

Every `scanf` argument (except for the format string) is effectively an "[out argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters)". It has to work that way, because there can be (and usually are!) more than one thing to read, yet you can only return one value from a function.

Comment: Aah, it works. Okay, that did the trick. But how does that work without touching the return value?

Comment: @Chris It's how [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) works. It takes a pointer so it can affect the pointed-to thing. Every `scanf` argument (except for the format string) is effectively an "[out argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters)". It has to work that way, because there can be (and usually are!) more than one thing to read, yet you can only return one value from a function